# Connect to both a wireless and wired connection simultaneously in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a client that needs to setup a small LAN at a trade show. Where their booth is located, there is no wired jacks; there is only public wireless being broadcast. They have a total of 3 laptops and the software they use requires that all 3 communicate amongst one another to properly function (they also need internet) The information being transmitted is sensitive information and can't be shared publicly. I have installed a router which will connect all three PC's with a wired connection and I also set each PC with a Static IP address, with NO Default GW on the wired network so they can use the wireless network to access the internet. I currently have the setup working, however it is not to my satisfaction, I am unable to set the wired connection as a private network (i'm assuming because there is no default gw), so I have to allow sharing on a public network. So my question is, does anybody have any better solutions or advice to make this work more securely.

Comment: With keeping information private, you'll need your own internet connection, not use the one offered by the event coordinators

Answer (score 0):

If you have an extra laptop you can use it as a modem. To do this, connect the laptop to the wireless signal.

Then go to Network and Sharing Center - > Change adapter settings

Highlight the Wireless Connection and The Local Area Connection at the same time.
-To do this you can drag a selection box over them or hold CTRL and select one at a time.

Once you have them both selected, right click and go to Bridge Connections.
-This will create an extra connection icon called Network Bridge.

Now connect the ethernet port of the laptop to the internet/WAN port on your router.

The laptop should now pass a connection on to the router. 
I tested this with all windows 7 computers and a dlink dir-615.
You may need to play around with your router settings to get this working. I had to change my LAN ip to something different then the wireless connection. You also may need to enter a static WAN ip to get a connection. I didn't have to in my scenario.